# Use sendmail without standard input

Tags: linux, command-line, email, sendmail, stdin

I would like to use `sendmail` to send an e-mail from my backup software on Kubuntu Linux. However the software does not allow entering a full command line (only command name and arguments pattern separately). This is why I can not pass the mail body to `sendmail` using standard input.

Is there a way to call `sendmail` without standard input usage? E.g. passing the message body by command line parameter (or even passing no body at all)?

Comment: You can probably get stdin to "work" this way: by spawning a shell with the redirections inside the argument:`sh -c 'sendmail -oi -t < file.eml'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, write a shellscript that does so.

```
#!/bin/sh
sendmail -i "silicomancer@example.com" <<EOF
Date: ...
From: ...
To: ...
Subject: ...
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Yo, stuff happened ($*).
EOF
```

Though it might be better to use `mail` (aka Mail or mailx or s-nail) than hand-craft all the headers.

Comment: The script is an interesting idea. However using an alternate mail program actually seems the better solution. 'sendemail' works like a charm for me.